# Is there any code requirements determining how close a ceiling fan can be to a pendant light?

Tags: lighting

Is there any code requirement on how close to a pendant light a ceiling fan blade can be? This is Oregon, which is based on  2018 IRC and 2020 NEC code.

Comment: code aside, the strobe effect from overlapping is highly undesirable.

Comment: Common sense, yes. Code, no. When you violate common sense, you'll get a lesson.

Comment: Why would you think there'd be a limit beyond "don't whack the pendant light with the ceiling fan blades?"

Answer (score 2):

Roundabout "code" reference.

Several fan makers specify 39 inches (remarkably/suspiciously close to 1 meter) as minimum clearance from fan-blade-tip to pendant-light-chain.

Code requires that you follow the maker's instructions.

So, if the maker of your fan has language like that, which may or may not have the same measurement, you should follow the instructions of the maker of your fan.

If not, you're back to what common sense will insist on teaching you.

Comment: And, if you refuse to use common sense, go with what (painful) experience teaches you.